# Does dynamic binding rules over the exception mechanism in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a class `A` that is derived from `std::exception` and have another class `B` derived from `A`. I already overrode the `what()` function for both classes `A` and `B`. I know that if I have catch block like this

```
catch(A& ob){
  std::cout << ob.what();
}
```

this will catch objects of type `A` and of type `B` which is derived from
`A`. But for `B` objects it also calls the `what()` function that is specific
to `A`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please, post a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: He probably just forgot `virtual`.

Comment: I tested this and it worked fine. http://goo.gl/ewrH0A

Comment: @Puppy, hard to forget it when it's on `std::exception::what()`

Answer (score 0):

The only way this can happen is if `B::what()` does not override the function in the base class, which will happen if it's signature doesn't match the function in the base class.

Make sure you didn't forget to make it `const` in `B`, to match `const char* what() const` in the base class.